# SQL - Return Output To Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure I have created so that I can enter lines into a table and subsequently return the INSERTED.ID so I can return this ID to the SQL Command that sent it to input the ID into that table.

I have used OUTPUT INSTEAD.ID before and this works fine when I do it as just an insert statement but how do I get the same result with a Stored Procedure.

I have done the following but can't seem to get it to output correctly.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_XStream_Send
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Dept VARCHAR(30),
@Process VARCHAR,
@RequestDT DATETIME,
@RequestType VARCHAR,
@RequestBranch INT,
@RequestPolRef VARCHAR,
@RequestXML VARCHAR,
@ReturnID INT OUTPUT    
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO dbo.XStream_Log
        ( Department ,
          Process ,
          RequestDT ,
          RequestType ,
          RequestBranch ,
          RequestPolicyRef ,
          RequestXML 
        )
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @OutputTbl(ID)
VALUES  ( @Dept,
@Process,
@RequestDT,
@RequestType,
@RequestBranch,
@RequestPolRef,
@RequestXML
        )


SELECT @ReturnID = ID FROM @OutputTbl

RETURN

END
GO
```

When i do the EXEC it wants me to send the @ReturnID but I don't want to Input anything into it, I want the output of the inserted ID.

Any help, cheers.

**UPDATE**

I am executing my stored procedure like so:

```
DECLARE @ID INT;
EXEC dbo.sp_XStream_Send @Dept = 'IT', -- varchar(1)
@Process = 'XStream Test', -- varchar(1)
@RequestDT = '2016-05-09 09:28:38', -- datetime
@RequestType = 'create-broomsrisk', -- varchar(1)
@RequestBranch = 0, -- int
@RequestPolRef = 'POMS01PC01', -- varchar(1)
@RequestXML = '<TestXML></TestXML>', -- varchar(1)
@ReturnID = @ID OUTPUT;
```

I am just getting 'Command(s) completed successfully' and not the actual ID.

Comment: Have you defined the @ReturnID parameter an output parameter upon execution of the stored procedure?
PS: Instead of the OUTPUT clause you could use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to retrieve the inserted ID. The current approach should be working, using SCOPE_IDENTITY just makes it a bit more readable an lightweight.

Comment: @MWillemse I have updated the above with what I am executing

Comment: Are you calling this SP from .NET or from another procedure?

Comment: Another Procedure Alex

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT @ID` after the execute statement?  I would expect that to return the output parameter value.